# Take and save multiple images and videos with OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, video

I'm using OpenCV and Python to take images and video. I would like to have OpenCV to take multiples pictures and videos when I click some specific letters on keyboard. But currently I can only take multiple images, I can't take a video at the same time. This is my current code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, time
video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
a=0
i=0

while True:
    a = a + 1
    check, frame = video.read()
    cv2.imshow("Capturing", frame)
    key=cv2.waitKey(1) 

    if key == ord ('r'):
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
        out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
        out.write(frame)
    if key == ord ('x'):
        i+=1
        cv2.imwrite('image'+str(i)+'.jpg', frame)
        cv2.imshow("Hasil Capture", frame)
        print('taking pictures')
    if key == ord ('q'):
        break


print(a)
video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```